# Stored procedure exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
SQL>  DECLARE
2    TotalUpd   NUMBER(36) := 0;
3  BEGIN
4   dbms_output.put_line ('Job Start time............... : ' || to_char(SYSDATE, '             hh24:mi:ss'));
5   UPDATE Asset SET _status = 'PROGRESS' WHERE status is null;
6   TotalUpd := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
7   dbms_output.put_line('Total Records Updated. : ' || TotalUpd);
8    COMMIT;
9   EXCEPTION
10   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
11  dbms_output.put_line ('No more data to update.');
12  WHEN OTHERS THEN
13  dbms_output.put_line ('Error while status as SUCCESS ');
14  END ;
15  /
```

The result for the above procedure is
    Job Start time............... : 04:41:41
    Total Records Updated. : 0

But my expected result is "No more row to be updated" must be printed,since i have truncated the table Asset.Please tell where I went wrong in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is as simple as the update does not geneate an error if there is no data.

you need to look at the value of `TotalUpd` if you want to control the flow of your code

```
 DECLARE 
 TotalUpd   NUMBER(36) := 0;
 BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Job Start time............... : ' 
        || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '             hh24:mi:ss'));
    UPDATE Asset SET _status = 'PROGRESS' WHERE status IS null;
    TotalUpd := SQL%ROWCOUNT; 
    IF TotalUpd = 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line ('No more data to update.');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('Total Records Updated. : '
            || TotalUpd);
    END IF; 
    COMMIT; 
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Error while status as SUCCESS '); 
 END;
```

Comment: You can add SQLERRM & SQLCODE while using WHEN OTHERS exception.
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR IS : ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM);

Comment: @Mahi007 - SQLERRM already includes SQLCODE. And handling an OTHERS exception with a debug message is not generally advisable.

Comment: remember I'm simply answering the question asked, I find it is best to assume that the functionality is correct, and there could there be a dependency on the output.

Comment: @William Robertson - Agree that Sqlerrm includes sqlcode. I was considering it as non production enviornment. Perhaps using 'when no data found` then Raise application error (-20001,<custom message> ) ` seem to be better option or alternatively insert into a ` error log table`

Answer (score 4):

The `NO_DATA_FOUND` error is not thrown in update statements.

It is thrown in `select into` statements if the select statement would return nothing.

See also [Tahiti on select into](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) under **select_item**: *If the SELECT INTO statement returns no rows, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception NO_DATA_FOUND.*

Oracle does not consider it an exception if an update statement does not update anything, hence no exception is thrown. However, if a select into statement cannot fill the variables, it is considered an error (and therefore in this case the NO_DATA_EXCEPTION is thrown(

Answer (score 1):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` is thrown if a `select into` does not return any row, not if no rows were updated after an update statement.

I suggest you move your logic for handling this exception after the update itself:

```
IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN  
  dbms_output.put_line ('No more data to update.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Think NO_DATA_FOUND exception is only raised by a SELECT statement which you aren't using. Try testing SQL%COUNT and output as required.

Comment: ...I guess you meant to write `SQL%ROWCOUNT`